# Cannot install dockprom

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to install dockprom(https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom). I follow the stepsgiven by them but I am getting this errors:

> ERROR: for caddy Cannot create container for service caddy: status
> code not OK but 500: {"Message":"Unhandled exception: Filesharing has
> been cancelled","StackTrace":" en
> Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.d__6.MoveNext() en
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\Mounting\FileSharing.cs:lĂ­nea
> 0\r\n--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicaciĂłn anterior
> donde se produjo la excepciĂłn ---\r\n en
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n en
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n en Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.d__4.MoveNext()
> en
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\Mounting\FileSharing.cs:lĂ­nea
> 47\r\n--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicaciĂłn anterior
> donde se produjo la excepciĂłn ---\r\n en
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n en
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n en
> Docker.HttpApi.Controllers.FilesharingController.d__2.MoveNext() en
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.HttpApi\Controllers\FilesharingController.cs:lĂ­nea
> 21\r\n--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicaciĂłn anterior
> donde se produjo la excepciĂłn ---\r\n en
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n en
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n en
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicaciĂłn anterior donde se
> produjo la excepciĂłn ---\r\n en
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n en
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n en
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicaciĂłn anteCreating grafana
> ... error
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n en
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
> Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicaciĂłn anterior donde se
> produjo la excepciĂłn ---\r\n en
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n en
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n en
> System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"}

And it is not only for caddy, I get same errors for Prometheus, caddy and Alertmanager